# jQuery .attr() and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I want to make the following use .attr();

```
selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value
```

sadly,

```
selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].attr("value")
```

is not the same, and seems to defeat the purpose of the .attr altogether.  My main question is: How should one use nested .attr()s?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an `attr` function. jQuery does. I've edited the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the value of any type of input element (including `<textarea>` and `<select>`) use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var value = $(selectbox).val();
```

The [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) translation would roughly be:

```
$(selectBox).find(":selected").attr("value");
```

....but just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) :)

The basic problem is that [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery method.  It's on jQuery objects, not on DOM elements directly, the same goes for almost *all* jQuery methods and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

When using attr(), you have to be working with a jQuery object. So first select the relevant select box, then call attr() (or val() in this case, when you need the value of an input element).

```
var value = $(selectbox).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to retrieve the selected box's value using your current code simply pass it into the jquery object like so.

```
$(selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex]).attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are not the same is because `attr('value')` gets the value of the `value` attribute directly from the original HTML code, **it is not updated with the DOM**, meaning if the value of `value` is changed after the page has loaded, either by user input (typing into an `<input>` element, or via manipulation with JavaScript, these changes will not be reflected in the returned value of `.attr()`.

A better way is to use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method of the jQuery object.

---

**Edit**
To get the attribute of the value from a DOM Element (i.e. not returned by the `$()` or `jQuery()` function) use the [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) method, which is native, you would use it like this:

```
selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: He intends to *get* the value, that's not the problem...it's that `.attr()` isn't even a valid method on the DOM element :)

Comment: Oh I see now, I just assumed he was using jQuery so I didn't look at his code and spot the non-jQueryness. Thanks :)