# Shuffle selected text on <textarea> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

When I select some texts on the `<textarea>` using my mouse, how can I shuffle/scramble it by clicking on a button?

I've searched for something similar to what I want here on SO, and I saw some who use `substring`, `selectionStart`, and `selectionEnd`.

What I want is: when I select some texts with my mouse, it will be shuffled/scrambled when I click on a button, and the rest of the texts on the `<textarea>` that are not selected should remain untouched/intact.

I just want to perform an action on the selected texts.

It's more similar to a rich text editor like when you select on some texts, then click on **bold** button, the selected texts will become **bold**.

*P.S.
It should be shuffled by individual characters.*

**EDIT:**
Got it! I just needed to separate the selection string. My code works now. This is very helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605191/1101391

Unfortunately, IE 9 and below does not support `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties on `<input>` and `<textarea>`. Here's the solution that worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276457/1101391

Comment: How should it be shuffled? By words, or by individual characters?

Comment: @Michael - Sir, it should be shuffled by individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the full text and know the substring where the selection starts and ends.  Try something like this:

```
var txtArea = document.getElementById("foo");
var before = txtArea.value.substr(0, txtArea.selectionStart);
var selection = txtArea.value.substr(txtArea.selectionStart, txtArea.selectionEnd + 1);
var after = txtArea.value.substr(txtArea.selectionEnd, txtArea.value.length);
txtArea.value = before + scrambleThisString(selection) + after;
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for your contribution. This just helped me figure out what was wrong with my code.

Comment: Bear in mind that `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are not supported in IE < 9.

Comment: Thank you, Sir @TimDown! +1 for pointing that out. Tried your recommendation from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9276457/1101391 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you name the textarea with ID `content`:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('content');
var content = textarea.value;

var start = textarea.selectionStart;
var end = textarea.selectionEnd;

var before = content.slice(0, start);
var after = content.slice(end);
var selected = content.substring(start, end);
selected = shuffleStringByMagic(selected);

textarea.value = before + selected + after;
```